# Rank with tied numbers

Tags: r, rank

I have to rank high values in a column of a data frame like this:

```
example <- data.frame(
      country=c("Arg","Uru","Arg","Uru","Arg","Uru","Arg","Uru"),
      value=c(1,1,2,3,4,5,6,10))
```

If I would rank the values with

```
example$rank<- rank(-example$value)
```

I would have something like this:

```
print(example$rank)
#[1] 7.5 7.5 6.0 5.0 4.0 3.0 2.0 1.0
```

When actually I am looking something like this:

```
#[1] 7 8 6 5 4 3 2 1
```

If they are tied, I don't mind which one has a higher rank.

Comment: Have a look at the `?rank` help page - there are many options for handling ties. `ties.method = "first"` will probably work for you (or `"last"`, or `"random"` - though that will be inconsistent between runs).

Comment: Thank you, Gregor, that helped me out!!